# Command Line args in C program using Netbeans

Tags: c, file, command-line-arguments, ubuntu-11.04, netbeans-7

I am new to usintg Netbeans in Linux. So, I am facing problem how to specify command line args for example A.txt and B.txt for my program in C using Netbeans. Its pretty simple to pass them as args using command line , but now for debugging purpose i need to use Netbeans 7.1 On Ubuntu version 11. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Using `gdb` you can specify command line arguments when you `run` the program ... `run A.txt B.txt`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Specifying command line arguments seems to have changed since netbeans 6.9 (I just checked).  To do this in 7.1, you have to go into **Project Properties > Run > Run Command** to set the arguments.

For example, to set the arguments **-foo -bar**, the Run Command setting would read:

**"${OUTPUT_PATH}" -foo -bar**